# Trouble in changing thickness of line segments in base plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a `pppmatching` object to plot (using the base plot function) where I need to change the thickness of line segments. Unfortunately, it seems that `lwd` is somehow changing the thickness of the **plot border** instead of the **line segments**! I am puzzled how to get around this.

Reproducible example:

```
library(spatstat)
set.seed(140627)
X <- runifpoint(300)
Y <- runifpoint(500)
m <- pppdist(X, Y)
m

plot(m, lwd = 5) #???
## End(Not run)
```

Comment: what installation of `spatstat` do you have? I can't sem to get `runifpoint` and `pppdist` functions

Comment: This should help https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.9-6/topics/pppdist.

Comment: This is a question about the `spatstat` package and should be tagged `spatstat`

Comment: Unfortunately `spatstat` is not a default tag and I do not have enough **reputation** to add it as a new one. Thanks for the great package and the nice response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about the plot method `plot.pppmatching` in the package `spatstat`. This function plots line segments between the data points, with varying line widths proportional to the matching strength. The parameter `lwd` would override this behaviour and would plot all lines with the same width, defeating the purpose.

**Text added later:**
Perhaps you wanted to rescale the line widths, multiplying/dividing them by 5 to make them more visible? This can be done using the argument `adjust`. For example `adjust=0.2` would divide all line widths by 5.

(In a future release of `spatstat` I will improve the documentation and suppress the irrelevant warning message)

Comment: as we discussed, this is just a reproducible example and referring back to my own dataset the line segments are plotted too thick so that I want to modify width of the line segments. I think it would be ideal to provide the possibility to modify the width of line segments for `pppdist` output.